# SOQL Date Comparison on Javascript Button

Tags: soql, javascript

I'm doing a Date comparison for NOW() on SOQL for javascript button but getting a MALFORMED QUERY Error:

```
     var d = new Date(); 
     alert(d);  
     var relatedrecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,(SELECT Id from Child_Records__r where Start_Time__c > d) from Order where Id = '{!Order.Id}'"); 
     var records = relatedrecords.getArray("records"); 
     if(records != null && records[0] != null){ 
        alert("Cannot cancel future records exists"); 
       }
```

Comment: Can you [update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/229970/edit) your question to include an exact quote of the full text of the error message? Can you also put a screenshot of the alert box that you are generating so we can see it's output? Lastly, have you compared the output from your alert to [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) to verify the format is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues I can see:

First, you're outputting "d" directly into your query, you are not adding the value of the date. You'd fix that by doing the following:

```
var relatedrecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,(SELECT Id from Child_Records__r where Start_Time__c > " + d + ") from Order where Id = '{!Order.Id}'");
```

Second, you need to verify that the value of d outputs in the correct format. You can verify that by comparing your alert output to [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

```
d.toISOString();
```

This should do the trick (thanks sfdcfox)

Comment: [`d.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) so you don't have to import jQuery plus an additional library.